# RwFromConstMem using a pointer to an array

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm building an intel 8080 emulator in Plain C. It reads a ROM file and keeps it into memory. Now I'm trying to make SDL render a bitmap in memory, it's like this right now:

```c
void updateScreen(Machine* machine) {
  unsigned char* buffer = &machine->state->memory[2400];
  SDL_RWops *screen = SDL_RWFromConstMem(buffer, 0x1C00 * sizeof(uint8_t));
  SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_LoadBMP_RW(test, 1);
}
```

Would this be the right way of doing so?

Memory is an array, and the from 2400 to 3fff is "VRAM". Would this work or it would give out errors? Also, the bitmap is in little endian, running it in my PC would make it render it wrong?

Comment: You tried it, didn't you? What did you see?

Comment: BMP have a special header; your data probably don't. If you only want to display pixmap you can create texture of the same format and copy your pixels there (look for `SDL_LockTexture` and `memcpy`)

Comment: @keltar I'm trying with textures now. Thanks :)